# Array of struct and sizeof

Tags: c, pointers, structure, void-pointers

I want to write, in C (no particolar flavour, lets say c11) a generic, global const array of struct, like the following pseudocode:

```
void * generic[] ={&(struct a va),&(struct b vb)};
```

Now I want to create a function that, given the id of the position of desired struct (I'm planning to use a const for every id, hardcoded), will copy it.

Because that `copy()` also is generic (accepts a `void *` as destination) it would need to know the strict size, witch may be specified by caller (a lot of error prone, he already need to provide the target structure and the right id) or i will also maintain a parallel array of correct `sizeof` for every structure.

Is there a way to automate at compile time the initialization of sizeof array? Or even implement some sort of trick to let the user specify just pass the pointer to struct without its id, without having to write a specialized `get_struct_x()`?

No dynamic allocation (`alloc()`, local variable are fine) allowed, all struct and generic array content is known at compile time.

Sorry for my bad explanation, feel free to improve/correct it.

Edit for clarification: i need to deep copy a know struct type from an array where there are stored many struct type, but the same type never repeat itself. And I need to do it from a generic get function witch will be called from different thread, so before and after the copy will lock a mutex, and I want to keep all the locking and casting code in one point, to minimize debug and create more effective test.

Comment: I think your question is, "Can I write a function which takes an array of `struct`s and an index and `struct` destination address as input -- such that the specific `struct` is bound 'somewhere else'?"

Comment: "Is there a way to automate at compile time the initialization of sizeof array?" the only mechanism that's available to you is the preprocessor.  It's the most common utility used for abstracting this kind of feature.

Comment: Is it an option to store the size of each struct inside itself? I.e., add a member `int mySize` as the first member in each struct, and set it (in runtime) to `x.mySize = sizeof(struct x)`.

Comment: Or make the void*array a struct container array, witch cointains size and void pointer. Still need the developer to pay attention on the size and struct dependency, but a lot less error prone and still static initialized. Any idea about the struct to id map generation?

Comment: I'm likely utterly lost. The sizeof *what*? Contrary to the description in the question, the *non-const* array of *non-const* `void *` ? The size of the array is trivial `sizeof(generic)/sizeof(*generic)` The size of each entity who's only path to glory is via a `void*` is not available. You could have an array of `struct { void* p; size_t len }` and properly populate the elements with instance address and sizeof(instance-type), but thats the only way out I see. Even then, there is no short-path to `sizeof (insert something here)` that will give you an immediate  size of the pointed-to-data.

Comment: @BrianCain cant get somewhere else. I know aboutpreprocesdor, but i can't see a way to do so. But never used macro seriusly, so any suggestion if viable way would be nice

Comment: @WhozCraig in the void* array, every element is a different struct, with different size. The array size and pointed struct address are const, and know at compile time, so i can hardcode the sizeof value, only data inside structure may change at runtime.

Comment: @lesto my point was they may be "constant" to you, but not in the code you defined. Both the pointer array and the pointers within are *not* `const` (language-defined) as written. And every element is *not* a different struct with different sizes. Every element in that array is a *pointer*; they're all the same size (the size of a pointer). What each address homes to isn't an attribute of `generic`, and as such you'll be forced to compute it per-item and computationally calculate the *sum-total* at runtime. I see no elegant way around that.

Comment: @whozcraig ok, the pointer size is know, but as specified i need to know the size of pointed struct to deep copy it. and in the *Pseudo*code things are not const, but it was an example (i dont even think it compile, actually)

Comment: @lesto the struct-method referred to by my first comment (and yours by the looks of it) is posted. Is *that* what you're trying to do, but without the `Entry` struct ?

Comment: Yes, this is a possible and valid answer, and i like it more the other one of user3386109 because similar to my idea, the #define you used is what i was looking for! But see my question edit to understand exactly why i want to to this, maybe you or someone else will have a better idea. Ill leave the question open until tomorrow because this, if no better answer will arrive your wins :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a friend of mine [s]without stackoverflow account[/s] (@Francesco) has re-elaborated the @WhozCraig answer adding the (very old) [X macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) (thanks to the [great article](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387) by Randy Meyers) to build the generic struct array AND the enum witch help to access the array's struct leaving the user to edit only one spot;

going back to work I've told him i would like to try to make the specific struct getter (as there will be NO REPEATED STRUCT TYPE in the array. if you get it wrong, compile time error, so at the end of the day you will bend your head while developing, but once compile it will be more robust), so we would have compilation check on the type of the requested struct;
back home he had already implemented it. KUDOS!

Then again I've lost some time on it and make to make the developer just have to type one time the struct, to prevent misalignment on that side;
this has been the beginning of an optimization spiral;

- because of specialized get and put, no more need of size array, so removed the generic struct
- no initialized structure needed, we use "anonymous" struct initialization
- because "anonymous" initialization, it is harder to directly access the structure
- direct access require knowledge of the system, with lead to awareness
- code it more readable
- easy to export `GENERIC_TABLE` and structure definition on external independent file
- #ifdef on `GENERIC_TABLE` works fine, move it to external header to increment readability
- no dynamic initialization needed outside local variable (no garbage, embedded friendly)
- extremely easy to use

cost

- maybe a bit preprocessor bloated?
- seems a lot OOP xD
- you may call get and put with uninitiated pointer

TL;DR: here the full compiling code and basic example:

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* BEGIN: just some struct to test, fell free to move them on external header file */
struct A
{
    int a1;
    long a2;
};

struct B
{
    float b1;
    char b2[6];
};

struct C
{
    unsigned int c1;
    double c2[5];
};
/* END: just some struct to test, fell free to move them on external header file */

/* this macro will create the right X macro element, and also initiliaze the "anonymous" struct */
#define ADD_STRUCT_TO_ARRAY(xu) X(xu, &(struct xu){})SEP

/* BEGIN: add or remove your own struct here! 
 * fell free to move them on external header file 
 * just need to pass struct name without "struct" to ADD_STRUCT_TO_ARRAY macro */
#define GENERIC_TABLE \
    ADD_STRUCT_TO_ARRAY(A) \
    ADD_STRUCT_TO_ARRAY(B) \
    ADD_STRUCT_TO_ARRAY(C)
/* END: add or remove your own struct here! */

/* here we initialize the enum, where the type of the struct is the key, and its position in the array the value */
#define SEP ,
#define X(a,b) a
enum STRUCT {
    GENERIC_TABLE
};
#undef X

/* here we initalize the array of pointer to the structure */
#define X(a,b) b
void * const generic[] =
{
    GENERIC_TABLE
};
#undef X
#undef SEP

/* here we create all the getter function. add here your array locking code */
#define SEP ;
#define X(a,b) void get_##a(struct a * dest){memcpy(dest, generic[a], sizeof(struct a) );} 
GENERIC_TABLE
#undef X
#undef SEP

/* here we create all the putter function. add here your array locking code */
#define SEP ;
#define X(a,b) void put_##a(struct a * source){memcpy(generic[a], source, sizeof(struct a) );}
GENERIC_TABLE
#undef X
#undef SEP

/*run, code, run!*/
int main()
{
    struct A a_copy;
    struct B b_copy;
    struct C c_copy;

    get_A(&a_copy);
    get_B(&b_copy);
    get_C(&c_copy);

    printf("STRUCTURE IN ARRAY BEFORE INITIALIZATION\n");
    printf("A = %d\n", a_copy.a1);
    printf("B = %f\n", b_copy.b1);
    printf("C = %x\n", c_copy.c1);

    a_copy.a1 = -1;
    b_copy.b1 = 2.3;
    c_copy.c1 = 3;

    printf("STRUCTURE CHANGED TO\n");
    printf("A = %d\n", a_copy.a1);
    printf("B = %f\n", b_copy.b1);
    printf("C = %x\n", c_copy.c1);

    printf("STRUCTURE SAVED\n");
    put_A(&a_copy);
    put_B(&b_copy);
    put_C(&c_copy);

    get_A(&a_copy);
    get_B(&b_copy);
    get_C(&c_copy);

    printf("STRUCTURE LOADED\n");
    printf("A = %d\n", a_copy.a1);
    printf("B = %f\n", b_copy.b1);
    printf("C = %x\n", c_copy.c1);

    a_copy.a1 = 1000;
    b_copy.b1 = -50.576;
    c_copy.c1 = 700;

    printf("STRUCTURE CHANGED TO\n");
    printf("A = %d\n", a_copy.a1);
    printf("B = %f\n", b_copy.b1);
    printf("C = %x\n", c_copy.c1);

    get_A(&a_copy);
    get_B(&b_copy);
    get_C(&c_copy);

    printf("STRUCTURE RELOADED WITHOUT SAVING\n");
    printf("A = %d\n", a_copy.a1);
    printf("B = %f\n", b_copy.b1);
    printf("C = %x\n", c_copy.c1);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without having to modify the underlying data structures, this is the only method I can see where this will be fairly manageable. Each entry in your array is *not* a `void*`, but rather a struct that contains an `void*` (to the element) and a `size_t` (sizeof data for that element):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Entry
{
    size_t len;
    void const *elem;
} Entry;

#define ELEM_ENTRY(x)   { sizeof(x), &(x) }

struct A
{
    int a1;
    long a2;
} a;

struct B
{
    float b1;
    char b2[6];
} b;

struct C
{
    unsigned int c1;
    double c2[5];
} c;

Entry generic[] =
{
    ELEM_ENTRY(a),
    ELEM_ENTRY(b),
    ELEM_ENTRY(c)
};
size_t generic_n = sizeof(generic)/sizeof(*generic);


int main()
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<generic_n; ++i)
        printf("[%zu] = %zu\n", i, generic[i].len);
}
```

**Output**

```
[0] = 8
[1] = 12
[2] = 44
```

I *think* that's what you're trying to do. if not, I'll drop this answer. Note that this will likely *not* work how you want it to if the element is a pointer type (but it *will* work how you want it to if it is a native *array* type). So be careful.

Comment: sorry to remove your accepeted answer, but see my own answer that do some more trick using X macro

Answer (score 0):

I would make the size of the struct the first element in every struct. So you have

```
struct a
{
   size_t size;
   int a1;
   double a2;
   // ... 
};

struct b
{
   size_t size;
   char b1[20];
   float b2;
   // ... 
};
```

Any time you create a struct, be sure to initialize the size, e.g.

```
struct a *aptr = malloc( sizeof(struct a) );
aptr->size = sizeof(struct a);
aptr->a1 = 3;
aptr->a2 = 100.5;

struct b someB = { sizeof(struct b), "hello", 1.0 };
```

Then, in the copy routine, you can cast the `void *` to a `size_t *` to get the size of the struct, since you know that every struct will have the size as the first element.

Comment: I generally like this approach better than the other two answers, but unfortunately the OP explicitly stated that `malloc()` is not allowed for the solution. So no +1 :-(